# web design to handle the virtual keyboard better - design feature overlooked, Android

Tags: html, css

**Main Point**:

I want to stop my website from resizing when the virtual keyboard is display.

**In Detail:**

I've been creating a web application to use on a android tablet. Looks beautiful on the laptop, looks fantastic on the tablet. There are parts in this application where the user input is needed and that is a design feature I overlooked.

Now when I click to 'Enter a Customer Name', the whole app gets squished when the virtual keyboard comes out. An issue I never noticed when designing on a computer.

for example:

```
<div className="container">
    <div className="sideBar"> 
        <button> 1 </button>
        <button> 2 </button>
        <button> 3 </button>
    </div>
    <div className="renderArea">
        <input 
          type="text"
          placeholder="Customer Name"
          value={createName}
         />
    </div>
</div>
```

and we have some css

```
.container {
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.sidebar {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width:20vw;
  height:100vh;
}
.render {
  width:80vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

This example would render a website that had a sidebar on the left and content in the middle. The sidebar would have 3 buttons, all spaced evenly.

When you click on the input text box, the keyboard appears up and squishes the three buttons up within the sidebar, or as much as it can. This can get really really ugly within other parts of my app.

I believe this has to do with flex box, but it's seems strange to remove it?

**A potentially bad solution**

I discovered `position:fixed` somewhat works but not for everything, and is super tedious.

Any solutions>

Comment: It's likely because you're using `height:100vh`. This is similar to a percentage based value where it will always set the height to X percentage of what ever the view port height is. To fix it, either remove it or use a px based value

Comment: The does solve it but then I could say that my website isn't as responsive to sizing as it was with using vh or vw. Using the pixel route would require @media styling. Is this the best/only solution?